# Python Requests: Check if Login was successful

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've looked all over the place for the solution I'm looking for but just can't find it. Basically, I'm developing a tool which takes a list of URLs from a text document, logs into them with your username/password, and returns which ones work.

I have the login figured out and all, but how do I actually return if the login works? Sites entered on the list won't necessarily use cookies and will be developed on various platforms.

Here's my login code:

```
r = requests.post(action, data=values, verify=False)
print(r.headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
print(r.url)
sleep(1)
```

I'd like everything after that first line to be in an if statement if the login actually works, but I can't figure out how to actually determine that.

Thanks.

Comment: status_code 200 means ok

Comment: if there is no absolutely no difference in the response between a successful and a failed login, the server side is probably doing something very wrong. If there is a difference, please post the result of your code that shows the response content for both cases

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `r.content` to check if you login or not, like string `success` or some flag means that you login.
if the `r.content` for login user and not login user are same, you can request a special link that need to login and find a flag to check.

Answer (score -1):

status bit will let you know

```
 r = requests.post(action, data=values, verify=False)
 authi = requests.get(r.url, auth=('user', 'pass'))

>>> authi.status_code
200
```

You will find more status bit info here

[STATUS CODE DEFINITION](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: I tried that but it returns 200 regardless of whether or not it actually logged in.

Comment: are you  using django or any other backened ?

Comment: I am not, only the base python and the following libraries:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import urllib.parse

Comment: so better to use the get request method